# Tell parent component to fetch new data

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and inside it a router outlet. In the router outlet I have a component that creates new objects related to the parent component. Can you please help me understand how do I communicate to the parent component that he has to make a new api call to get the latest data ?

I was thinking of creating a service that will have a rebuild = new BehaviourSubject(false) and the parent should listen to it and make new request if the value changes to true. Can you please help me understand how I should tackle this problem ?

Comment: The official tutorial has an entire section on this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicationService } from './communication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private communication: CommunicationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.communication.tell$.subscribe((msg) => {
      // call an api here
      console.log(msg);
    });
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicationService } from './communication.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <button (click)="communication.tell('hello')">
    Tell parent
  </button>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor(public communication: CommunicationService) { }
}
```

**communication.service.ts**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {
  private tellSource = new Subject();
  tell$ = this.tellSource.asObservable();

  tell(msg: string) {
    this.tellSource.next(msg);
  }
}
```

**routing configuration**

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', component: ChildComponent },
]
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bqtjm)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Why subjects instead of BehaviorSubjects though ?

Comment: If you need an initial value, you can use BehaviorSubject. That's the only difference.

Comment: The thing that I don't understand in your answer is the following. If i already made a call in ngOnInit to have data( both parent and child component are displayed at the same time) and i need that data to change. This won't trigger ngOnInit again. Or how can I avoid multiple api requests